# Limit roles displayed in users.php depending on custom role

Tags: users, user-roles

I have setup my WordPress installation with a custom role called **'regional_manager'**

I have given this role the capability to add_users and managed to create a custom snippet for my functions.php file which only lists subscribers in the Role drop down.  This means that the regional_manager role can only create new users with a role of subscriber.

Now I would like to prevent them from seeing all other users when they go to

```
www.mydomain.com/wp-admin/users.php
```

Is there a simple way to do this and does anyone have an example of something similar they can point me in the direction of?

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the source of that file at the very top there is capability check:

```
if ( ! current_user_can( 'list_users' ) )
    wp_die( __( 'Cheatin&#8217; uh?' ) );
```

So `list_users` seems like a perfect starting point (at least) to remove from your custom role. However it is hard to say what else it might affect without thoroughly testing out all parts of admin your user should and should not be able to use.